# WordPress on Localhost with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, localhost

I have installed WordPress (latest) on a local server which is running on UniServer.
The installation finished OK and I was able to navigate around the admin area and added a couple of posts.
Looking from the front end, everything worked.

I then changed the Permalink setting to 'Post name' and, when I saved it I revceived an error "Forbidden - You don't have permission to access /wp-admin/options-permalink.php on this server."

On checking I found that if I deleted the .htaccess file I regained access and could reset the Permlink setting to 'Plain'.
Changing to anything but 'Plain' causes a .htaccess file to be created and no access.

The Apache error log shows the following: -
"[Wed Mar 21 12:35:04.297002 2018] [rewrite:error] [pid 14192:tid 1908] [client ::1:52537] AH00670: Options FollowSymLinks and SymLinksIfOwnerMatch are both off, so the RewriteRule directive is also forbidden due to its similar ability to circumvent directory restrictions : D:/WEBS/js/wp-admin/options-permalink.php, referer: http://localhost/wp-admin/options-permalink.php"

I have used Google to search this message and have been round in circles with changes to the .htaccess file and also httpd.conf to no avail.

The .htaccess file that is created is as follows: -

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I have followed what is posted here: [https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks]

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Is your rewrite on at local server?

Comment: I have managed to understand part of the problem.
When I added SymLinksIfOwnerMatch to the .htaccess file it seems that WordPress was removing the line.

Adding "Options Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch" to the 'DocumentRoot' in httpd.conf file resolves the issue!

Only question now would be do I need all of the options that I added??!?!?

Comment: @ dipmala - yes rewrite is enabled as a module

Comment: @itfidds make screen shot from options-permalink page and add it to question

Answer (score 1):

OK, the solution appears to be that SymLinks needs to be enabled.

So, I added the following to .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
```

What I did not notice was that, when I changed the Permalinks option in WordPress, the code above was stripped out.

So after further searching on Google and testing with the httpd.conf file I found that by adding the following line to DocumentRoot works

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
```

I am not convinced that I need all of the options and, time permitting, with try to understand the consequences of each one and whether they are required.

However, for now, I can access the WordPress site locally again with PermaLinks set to 'Post name'.